# How to remove Continue button from MSAL email verification page while signup

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

I am using MSAL angular.

I need to remove the `Continue` button from email verification page.

[image]

Comment: Is that HTML template under your control? If so, what does it look like?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.